# jupyter kernels in OSX: No module named IPython

Tags: python, macos, ipython, anaconda, jupyter

**Quick side note**:

This question is based on issue [#7947](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/7947) in `ipython`'s bug tracker. The problem seems to be an issue related to either `OSX`, or some weird settings on my mac (maybe both). I cannot reproduce it on a fresh Ubuntu box.

I am aware that the underlying problem could be complex. Knowing if it is reproducible on `OSX` or if it's just me would already be a great help.

---

I am trying to set up multiple `jupyter` kernels for my python versions. Specifically I have two `conda` environments `sci27` and `sci34`, as the names already suggest the former runs a `python2.7` interpreter, the latter a `python3.4` interpreter.

So what I do now is:

```
source activate sci27
conda install ipython-notebook
ipython kernelspec install-self
```

Now I have my kernel definition in `/usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/python2/`

```
{
 "display_name": "Python 2",
 "language": "python",
 "argv": [
  "/Users/ch/miniconda/envs/sci27/bin/python",
  "-m",
  "IPython.kernel",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ]
}
```

I start `ipython` in my `sci34` environment:

```
source activate sci34
conda install ipython-notebook
ipython notebook --debug
```

And now things are getting weird: If I select the freshly installed kernel `Python 2`, the kernel crashes with following output:

```
[D 12:47:53.029 NotebookApp] Opening websocket /api/kernels/4ae0a266-9396-44f7-a529-912056dc6eed/channels
[D 12:47:53.029 NotebookApp] Connecting to: tcp://127.0.0.1:52954
[D 12:47:53.030 NotebookApp] Connecting to: tcp://127.0.0.1:52955
[D 12:47:53.031 NotebookApp] Connecting to: tcp://127.0.0.1:52956
[I 12:47:54.949 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (4/5)
WARNING:root:kernel 4ae0a266-9396-44f7-a529-912056dc6eed restarted
[D 12:47:54.954 NotebookApp] Connecting to: tcp://127.0.0.1:52957
/Users/ch/miniconda/envs/sci34/bin/python: No module named IPython
[W 12:47:57.957 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restart failed
[W 12:47:57.957 NotebookApp] Kernel 4ae0a266-9396-44f7-a529-912056dc6eed died, removing from map.
ERROR:root:kernel 4ae0a266-9396-44f7-a529-912056dc6eed restarted failed!
[W 12:47:57.975 NotebookApp] Kernel deleted before session
[W 12:47:57.975 NotebookApp] 410 DELETE /api/sessions/70f4d715-807c-4bbc-8a0a-b503aa966606 (::1) 1.40ms referer=http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Untitled2.ipynb?kernel_name=python2
```

The message `/Users/ch/miniconda/envs/sci34/bin/python: No module named IPython` is rather surprising to me. Why would `jupyter` try to call `sci34`'s interpreter instead of `sci27`'s interpreter?

Also, why the `module not found` message? Obviously `/Users/ch/miniconda/envs/sci34/bin/python -m IPython` works perfectly fine, as the notebook server runs from the `sci34` environment.

Comment: Are there any kernels in `~/.ipython/kernels`, or in `/Users/ch/miniconda/envs/sci34/share/jupyter/kernels`?

Comment: @ThomasK, there is a `julia` and an `R` kernel in `~/.ipython/kernels`, but no other python kernel. There is no kernel in the `share` directory of the sci34 environment.

Comment: Do you have the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable set?

Comment: @asmeurer, seems to be unset.

Comment: Another possibility, do you have any directories in your current directory named `ipython`? That can screw IPython up in Python 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to `IPython 3.2.0` will fix this issue. For details see pull request [PR-8527](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/8527).